# How are we able to use ApplicationBar as a variable or object when it is a type in .netframework (Windows phone app development prospective)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8

CODE:

```
    private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from             AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton RecordButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        RecordButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarRecord;
        RecordButton.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/microphone.png", UriKind.Relative);
        RecordButton.Click += RecordButton_Click;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(RecordButton);

        // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarMenuItem AboutMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
        AboutMenuItem.Text = AppResources.AppBarAbout;
        AboutMenuItem.Click += AboutMenuItem_Click;
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(AboutMenuItem);
    }
```

DOUBT :

how are  we using ApplicationBar as a variable or object when it is a type . (line 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApplicationBar is **also** a property of PhoneApplicationPage:

```
public class PhoneApplicationPage : Page
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ApplicationBarProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SupportedOrientationsProperty;

    public PhoneApplicationPage();

    public IApplicationBar ApplicationBar { get; set; }
    public PageOrientation Orientation { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and you can use it as a property of a page you are using.
Normally you create it with a constructor from a class ApplicationBar:

```
public sealed class ApplicationBar : IApplicationBar
{
    public ApplicationBar();
    public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public IList Buttons { get; }
    public double DefaultSize { get; }
    public Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsMenuEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public IList MenuItems { get; }
    public double MiniSize { get; }
    public ApplicationBarMode Mode { get; set; }
    public double Opacity { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<ApplicationBarStateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged;
}
```

and thus you have access to properties as above in that class. Which you can use in your page like this:

```
(ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton).Text = "my first button text";
```

In a line above you refer to a property `ApplicationBar` from your page, and its property `Buttons` from class `ApplicationBar`.
**EDIT** - about IApplicationBar
Your ApplicationBar class implements interface IApplicationBar which is a reference type. ApplicationBar must provide an implementation for all the members of the IApplicationBar:

```
public interface IApplicationBar
{
    Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    IList Buttons { get; }
    double DefaultSize { get; }
    Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    bool IsMenuEnabled { get; set; }
    bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    IList MenuItems { get; }
    double MiniSize { get; }
    ApplicationBarMode Mode { get; set; }
    double Opacity { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<ApplicationBarStateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged;
}
```

It means that your `ApplicationBar` property (PhoneApplicationPage) can be any instance of a class that implements IApplicationBar.
You can read more about inheritance, interfaces and more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Comment: In my code , i am setting the ApplicationBar to the instance of a ApplicationBar class .Then it's type should be ApplicationBar but how come it is IApplicationBar ??

Comment: @varunsinghal65 I've edited my answer and added a little about interface which is a reference type for ApplicationBar.